# Как убрать склейку строк при работе PHP скрипта?

Tags: php, парсер, скрипт

Есть PHP скрипт-парсер, он кроном каждую минуту собирает по API данные и добавляет эти данные в конец вот этого файла: **sbor_proxy_s_dybliami.txt** .

Файл **sbor_proxy_s_dybliami.txt** - я блокирую для записи для других скриптов на время работы данного скрипта, это я делаю в строке:

```
file_put_contents($file, $String, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

**Вопрос:** что нужно исправить в коде скрипта-парсера, чтоб избавится от "склейки" нескольких строк в результатах работы стрипта (в файле **sbor_proxy_s_dybliami.txt** ) ?

**Код PHP скрипта-парсера:**

```html
<?php
function Parse ($p1, $p2, $p3) {
}
$String = "\n".file_get_contents('https://api.best-proxies.ru/proxylist.txt?key=bf030000000000000000ab2&country=al&limit=0');
$file = 'sbor_proxy_s_dybliami.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $String, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

?>
```

Ниже прикладываю скриншоты проблемы склейки из файла **sbor_proxy_s_dybliami.txt**
**2 строки в одном ряду:**
[image: 2 строки в одном ряду:]

**и так по всему файлу:**

[image: и так по всему файлу:]

Comment: Используйте PHP_EOL вместо \n

Comment: Простите нуба), я писал этот скрипт по мануалу. Поэтому не знаю как прописать PHP_EOL в мой скрипт. Исправьте пожалуйста мой скрипт.

Comment: @Михаил: я не вижу ошибок в Вашем коде.. перевод строки стоит, и нормально отрабатывает. Может это API отдает неверные данные (склеенную строку)?

Comment: @Михаил: попробуйте какое- то время каждый ответ писать в отдельный файл

Comment: API нормально все отдает. Вот посмотрите по ссылке отображение в "коде элемента" как отдает результаты парсер прямо в браузер, а не в txt : http://elisee84.bget.ru/test1.php Проблема в том, что когда через 1 минуту скрипт добавляет в конец этого txt файла новую порцию данных, то видимо он не с новой строки вставляет, а вставляет в последнюю строку в которой уже есть данные от первого добавления (которое было 1 минуту назад) вот см скриншот: http://prntscr.com/rqx30v

Comment: Проблема в том что на разных платформах новая линия считается [по-разному](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Перевод_строки).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажите, пожалуйста, содержимое файла после выполнения следующего кода (подставьте свой ключ):

```
$eof = PHP_EOL . "---" . PHP_EOL;
$string = file_get_contents('https://api.best-proxies.ru/proxylist.txt?key=bf030000000000000000ab2&country=al&limit=0') . $eof;
$file = 'sbor_proxy_s_dybliami.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

upd: Замените содержимое файла parser.php на указаный ниже код, и будет Вам счастье!

```
<?php

$string = file_get_contents('https://api.best-proxies.ru/proxylist.txt?key=bf030000000000000000ab2&country=al&limit=0') . PHP_EOL;
$file = 'sbor_proxy_s_dybliami.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: Вот скриншот с результатами в файле sbor_proxy_s_dybliami.txt после нескольких запусков скрипта:
http://prntscr.com/rr216h

 Вставил ваш код и несколько раз запустил:

>!

<?php
function Parse ($p1, $p2, $p3) {
}
$eof = PHP_EOL . "---" . PHP_EOL;
$string = file_get_contents('https://api.best-proxies.ru/proxylist.txt?key=bf03f8000000000000042ab2&country=al&limit=0') . $eof;
$file = 'sbor_proxy_s_dybliami.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

?>

 

Как сделать чтоб он не ставил: ---
??

Comment: @Михаил, очевидно же, убрать `"---" .`

Comment: @Михаил: обновил ответ. просто вставьте код вместо того, что у Вас.

Comment: @ArchDemon: )))

Comment: @Yakoffka огромное спасибо! ваш код  работает безукоризненно! 
вот окончательный код:
<?php
function Parse ($p1, $p2, $p3) {
}
$eof = PHP_EOL .  PHP_EOL;
$string = file_get_contents('https://api.best-proxies.ru/proxylist.txt?key=bf0300000000000002ab2&country=al&limit=0') . $eof;
$file = 'sbor_proxy_s_dybliami.txt';
file_put_contents($file, $string, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);

?>